# Design an expandable list with recycler view and supporting grid layout for child views in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

[image]I am trying to design a recycler view with expandable design , it will have groups which on click would open and show child views. But the child views need to support linear layout and grid layout as well.

Currently I am using a recycler view within another recycler view to achieve the same, and used expandable layout for expanding collapsing items. This does get me the desired effect but neither is it a good programming practice and nor is it bug free. It does some unexpected things at all times, which is really annoying and a bad UX experience.

Please tell me other reliable and bug free ways to do it.

This image is approximately what I am trying to achieve. Cannot show the actual work I have done because of company policy.

I am not asking to source code to solve my problem, but some general design directions to achieve the same goal. As mentioned before, what I did, using recycler view inside another did do the trick, but also created other problems(unpredicatble behaviour to say the least.)

Comment: ... or maybe your design doesn't make much sense. For me reading it, it's very difficult to understand, from your writing, what are you trying to accomplish, and why. Because it's UI, you could easily add a couple of pictures / drawing that explains it. Also, "Please tell me other reliable and bug free ways to do it" sounds to me so much like "please someone else do the homework for me". Last but not least, this is software, there's no such thing as 'bug free' in software, the only bug free code is the one which doesn't execute.

Comment: You should probably open your groups inside Fragments, maybe create a transition between them. But i think when you have so much different views hidden inside a Recyclerview it will get difficult to keep it  performant and probably will get confusing to the user.

Comment: I will edit to explain better my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using nested scroll view and setting the inner recycler views to 'setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)' did the trick. Now I can make what I wanted to after all.